# Javascript replace an element with a string

Tags: javascript

How can you change this

```
<div id='myDiv'><p>This div has <span>other elements</span> in it.</p></div>
```

into this

```
<div id='myDiv'>This div has other elements in it.</div>
```

hopefully using something like this

```
var ele = document.getElementById('myDiv');
while(ele.firstChild) {
    replaceFunction(ele.firstChild, ele.firstChild.innerHTML);
}
function replaceFunction(element, text) {
    // CODE TO REPLACE ELEMENT WITH TEXT
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219845%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) if you want to remove all descendant nodes, but leave the text:

```
// Microsoft
ele.innerText = ele.innerText;
// Others
ele.textContent = ele.textContent;
```

If you only want to flatten certain ones, you can define:

```
function foldIntoParent(element) {
  while(ele.firstChild) {
    ele.parentNode.insertBefore(ele.firstChild, ele);
  }
  ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
}
```

should pull all the children out of `ele` into its parent, and remove `ele`.

So if `ele` is the `span` above, it will do what you want.  To find and fold all the element children of `#myDiv` do this:

```
function foldAllElementChildren(ele) {
  for (var child = ele.firstChild, next; child; child = next) {
    next = child.nextSibling;
    if (child.nodeType === 1 /* ELEMENT */) {
      foldIntoParent(child);
    }
  }
}

foldAllElementChildren(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Looks like all I needed was ele.textContent all along.

Comment: @jchavannes, It's nice when the simplest solution works.  Keep `innerText` in mind when you test on IE.

Comment: It's actually a firefox addon so I don't need to worry about IE :P

Comment: btw, I tried using your function in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdE5e/ and it seemed to remove the <p> but not the <span>

Comment: @jchavannes, Yes.  You will need to recurse if you want to flatten.  Flattening one element at a time gives you more control but requires more work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using jQuery, stripping the HTML from an element and leaving only the text is as simple as:

```
$(element).html($(element).text());
```

Comment: Can't use jQuery.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the **innerText**

```
console.log(ele.innerText)
```